# Monitoring IBM MQ with java

Tags: java, monitoring, ibm-mq, metrics

How do I discover the Queue depth, and other metrics about queues, from IBM MQ using java with standard IBM MQ libraries?

Comment: Check out this answer from @Roger: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190771/how-to-display-local-queues-where-curdepth-reached-its-maxdepth-in-ibm-mq/62199810#62199810

Comment: I would make this as a duplicate of that question, but I couldn't since the answer on that question was not accepted.

Comment: I also suggest taking a look at https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?cat=67 for many Java samples that use IBM MQ PCF to access queue details from @Roger.

Comment: Thank you @JoshMc !
You helped a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the below sample code snippet for fetching the queue depth.

```
String mqQMgr = "";
String mqQueue = "";

MQEnvironment.hostname = "";
MQEnvironment.port = "";
MQEnvironment.channel = "";    
MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);

MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(mqQMgr);
MQQueue destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(mqQueue, openOptions);

int depth = destQueue.getCurrentDepth();
destQueue.close();
qMgr.disconnect();
```

A full code version (Change your parameters accordingly, like Bindings or client mode, options etc ) :

```
import com.ibm.mq.*;

public class QueueManager {

    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private final String channel;
    private final String manager;
    private final MQQueueManager qmgr;

    public QueueManager(String host, int port, String channel, String manager) throws MQException {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.qmgr = createQueueManager();
    }


    private MQQueueManager createQueueManager() throws MQException {
        MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
        MQEnvironment.port = port;
        MQEnvironment.hostname = host;
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
        return new MQQueueManager(manager);
    }

    // This method will return the Queue Depth
    public int queueDepth(String queueName) {
       int depth = -1;
       int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
       MQQueue queue = null;
       try {
          queue = qmgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);
          depth = queue.getCurrentDepth();
       }
       catch (MQException e)
       {
          System.out.println("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
       }
       finally {
          try {
             if (queue != null)
                queue.close();
          }
          catch (MQException e) {
             System.out.println("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
          }
       }

       return depth;
    }

    ........ Other Methods .......
}
```

Comment: @ЕвгенийЧижиков : Glad to know that, if my code helped you u can please upvote my answer.

Comment: @Som you have a memory leak in your queueDepth method.  You never close the queue, so every time the queueDepth method is called, it is leaking memory.  Rule # 1, if you open it, make sure you close it.  Same thing applies to a connection to a queue manager.

Comment: @Roger : Hi Roger , As the class is very long, I did not give all the methods. I have all the close methods implemented properly for queue, session, qgr, I have also rollback and commit implemented. But intentionally I have opted them out

Comment: @Som it is a bad idea to give partial code snippets and expect the programmer to know that there are other things they need to do.  Programmers will simply copy & paste your code into there application and think they have a complete solution.