# I need to write a Java Webservice which will produce the Queue Depth (int value) Currently What I have is simple JMS app which find queue depthdepth?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

```
//ctx is InitialContext
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/CF");
Connection conn = cf.createConnection();
conn.start();

Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("jms/MyQueue");
QueueBrowser qb = session.createBrowser(queue);

//sadly, getting this enum is the best the JMS API can offer.
//but the upside is the code is portable AND it can run over MQ and SIBus
//implementations.
Enumeration queueMessageEnum = qb.getEnumeration();
int count = 0;
while(queueMessageEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
  queueMessageEnum.nextElement();
  count++;
}
```

//how can i make this as soap web service so it can product queuedepth value

Comment: Is there a real need for finding out the queue depth? Why not simply consume messages as and when they arrive? If really required, then you need to use provider specific classes, in this case IBM MQ PCF classes. JMS classes don't provide such APIs.

Comment: Actually; The queuedepth (int) value has to be consumed by .net service and show on UI

Comment: You will need to use MQ Java PCF classes to do that. Refer the PCF samples shipped with the product.

Comment: can we use PCF in JMS , because our MQ is configured in WAS (websphere application sever) .

Answer (score 2):

If the current queue depth is for a GUi window then fine but do not ever consume messages based on current queue depth.

There are 2 ways by Java (not Java/JMS) to retrieve the current queue depth: inquire on queue or MQ PCF command of MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q.

If you want to use MQ PCF command then see my complete example here: [How to display local queues where curdepth reached its maxdepth in ibm mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190771/how-to-display-local-queues-where-curdepth-reached-its-maxdepth-in-ibm-mq/62199810#62199810)

To inquire on a queue, you simply do the following:

```
MQQueue inQ = qMgr.accessQueue( qName, CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING)
System.out.println("Current depth is " + inQ.getCurrentDepth());
inQ.close();
```

Note: You can use the same code in a .NET application to inquire on a queue.

Comment: Only showing the depth is easy. I want as web service .  I need the value to be consumed by some other service( .net) and show it on UI .

Comment: @Zahid this is a MUCH better way to find the depth than counting each message on the queue.   What happens if there are 300k messages on the queue.   StackOverflow is not a code writing service,  if you have specific questions about your own  code you can ask them here.

Comment: @Zahid, seems like your question is 'How do I create a REST API in Java?'. I know you said SOAP, but REST will be better. As that is such a broad question you will need to find an appropriate tutorial try it, and if you get stuck post sample code and the errors you are seeing as a new question. Otherwise take the advice that others have offered, and the core of your REST API should use MQ PCF. It will be much more efficient, especially when there are 100s or 1000s of messages on the queue. If you have the IBM MQ JMS jar files, then you also have the java classes for PCF.