# How to write Mq command to display curdepth is greater than 80%of maxdepth?

Tags: ibm-mq

How to write runmqsc Mq command to display queues for curdepth is greater than 80% of maxdepth? I have tried but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with native MQSC commands alone.

It is possible to do this if you use [MQSCX](https://www.mqgem.com/mqscx.html) from MQGem Software and the `=WHERE` clause (an enhancement over the IBM MQ `WHERE` clause). Then you can use the following command:-

```
DISPLAY QLOCAL(*) =WHERE(CURDEPTH GT MAXDEPTH * 0.8)
```

Comment: Can we work display query using shell scripting?

Comment: Of course - you can issue a command `DISPLAY QLOCAL(*) MAXDEPTH CURDEPTH` and then compare the two numbers yourself in your script. Any particular platform/script you wanted to use? Not that I ever do this because MQSCX is soooo much simpler.

Comment: Thank you Morag.. I'm trying commands in Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

As Morag said, runmqsc does not support what you want.  I posted a Java/MQ program that basically does what you want.  You can find the code here: [How to display local queues where curdepth reached its maxdepth in ibm mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190771/how-to-display-local-queues-where-curdepth-reached-its-maxdepth-in-ibm-mq/62199810#62199810)

Comment: Is possible to display above query using shell scripting?

Comment: Yes, you can run a Java program from a shell script.